# pop up setup on click event on reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

this is setting inside a available menu list
[image]

when I click on edit images(link) to open this  popup

[image]

I want when I click on first menu then show me menu name and popup always be displayed with a menu name

may be : if else to possible or not

and important is inside a popup i want to call a different api also

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+popup+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Don't just post pictures

Comment: it is simple html code not more important

Comment: So you cannot be bothered reading how to ask questions here. Good luck getting answers then